# External table using tab delimited file

Tags: sql, oracle, external-tables

I have a file that contains tab delimited data. Something like the following

```
id    f_name    l_name    m_name    dob        add_date  

100   john      smith     r         19880212   20161010  

102   micheal   ford                19920707   20161010
```

I use the following script to load data through `external table`

```
CREATE TABLE student_info(ID NUMBER, F_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    L_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    M_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    DOB DATE, ADD_DATE DATE) 
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL(TYPE ORACLE_LOADER 
                      DEFAULT DIRECTORY DATA_FILE_DIR 
                      ACCESS PARAMETERS(RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE 
                                   BADFILE bad_file_dir: 'STUDENT_COMP_INFO.bad'
                                   LOGFILE log_file_dir: 'STUDENT_COMP_INFO.log'
                                   SKIP 1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY 0X '09'
                                     OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LRTRIM MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL) LOCATION(FILE_DIR: 'STUDENT_COMP_INFO.txt')) REJECT
LIMIT
UNLIMITED;
```

Data load successfully in the data but when I select the data from the table I am getting the following output.

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT_INFO  

'ID'   'F_NAME'   'L_NAME'   'M_NAME'     'DOB'       'ADD_DATE'  

'100'  'john'     'smith'    'r'          '19880212'  '20161010'  

'102'  'micheal'  'ford'     '19920707'   '20161010'
```

So basically it won't consider the `Null` values. How can I properly load values in each fields even though if it is `Null`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Also, please do not post images of text, it makes it difficult for people to both search and copy-paste to try to help you. Your question should be self contained, and not require users to go to external sites to have all the information. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same behaviour. The (workaround) solution was to remove

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Seems like a bug to me. At least there is a workaround and you can remove the enclosing character in a second step.